# Is there any other tools like Ncalc available for .Net development?

Tags: .net

I am currently using [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) to perform some calculation at server side and it works great, but I am interested in to knowing if there are any commerical thrid party tools available? I am more interested in excel like features, like if/else, sum, min, max not just simple arithmatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a commercial product: http://www.bestcode.com/html/bcparser_net.html

But are you having any issues with NCalc?

Comment: I am currently using NCalc and want to compare it against any available ones to see how it perform to prove it.